# onclick and href both in anchor tag

Tags: javascript

How to do **onclick** and **href** both in **anchor tag**, in javascript.
*my code is :*

```
enter code here

for (l = 0; l < k; l++) {
    var tmp1 = searched_headings_filename[l];
    var tmp2 = searched_headings[l];
    frameDoc.body.innerHTML += '<div style="margin-left:10;"><li class="highlight"><a onclick="highlightSearch();" href="' + tmp1 + '">' + searched_headings[l] + '</a></li></div>';
}
```

Please help me...

Comment: What do you mean by `How to do onclick and href both in anchor tag,`?

Comment: Let the method navigate to the href too.

Comment: What's the issue you're having? What do you want to happen?

Comment: May I suggest you never use a lowercase letter L (`l`) as a variable name, it looks like the number one (`1`) and makes the code hard to read - especially as an array index: `searched_headings[l]`.

Comment: First JS function will be called, that you specify on "onclick". After that it will redirect. or Just write a redirect URL in JS function.

Comment: I want to open the HTML file(tmp1) and highlight the searched word, in that file. for highlighting the word i am going to use javascript function "highlightSearch()". so, for this two purpose i need onclick and href, both functionalities in anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to run some js function on click, and then redirect to whatever is in the href? Try this

```
<a href="javascript:YourFunctionName(someParameter);">displayName</a>
```

Then in js function

```
function YouFunctionName(someParameter){
    // do your logic
    window.location = 'someUrlYouWantToRedirectTo';
};
```

Comment: I tried it. but it's saying the error as, "The value of the property 'highlightSearch' is null or undefined, not a function object"

Comment: I would have to see the whole code in order to advise you what is wrong